# Monitor HTTPS requests and responses using Google Cloud Alerts

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, alerts, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to create an `uptime check` alert in Google Cloud Monitoring.
The `TARGET` is an `HTTPS URL`. This `URL` requires some headers and body data.
The `HEADER data` is added under `"MORE TARGET OPTIONS"`.
But where would the `Body data` be added?

The curl command for the request is like

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<url>' \
--header 'TOKEN': 'token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[ {<test-json-data>} ]'
```

How can I send the --data-raw (body data) in google uptime check?

Comment: We can add body data to the uptimecheck via API. In this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.uptimeCheckConfigs/create) go to **Try this API**. In the request body field you can add different request body parameters like httpCheck,contentType,body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#create):

> To issue an HTTP POST request for an uptime check, you must create the uptime check by using the Cloud Monitoring API.

The UI won't let you do this.